# Prove by induction that $(n - 1)^k \le n^k$

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-theorem

Let $n,k \in \mathbb N, n \gt 0$.

I was trying to prove by induction that:
$$
(n - 1)^k \le n^k
$$
(The induction is meant to be on k.)
I started by verifying the inequality in the base cases, which I did by $k = 0$ and $k = 1$, so:
$$
(n - 1)^0 = 1 \le 1 = n^0
\\
(n - 1)^1 = n - 1 \le n = n^1
$$

then I have to prove it in the inductive step, so I assume that $(n - 1)^{k} \le n^{k}, \space \forall \space k' < k$:
$$
(n - 1)^{k + 1} = (n - 1)^k (n - 1) \le n^k n = n^{k + 1}
$$

If I am not wrong, the proof is correct, because in the inductive step I got $(n - 1)^k$ which I assumed to be less or equal than $n^k$ and $(n - 1)$ is less or equal than $n$ by the base case.
So the product of $(n - 1)^k$ and $(n - 1)$ isn't greater than the product $n^k$ and $n$.
Am I right?

Comment: What is $n{}{}$?

Comment: Is the induction meant to be on $n$ or $k$? Please include *full* details of the question.

Comment: What are the natures of $k$ and $n$? Are they real? Natural? Integers?

Comment: Proving false assertions is often more challenging than proving true assertions.  Consider $$(0.2)^2 ~~\text{versus}~~ (0.2 - 1)^2.$$

Comment: I have fixed the errors.

Comment: Induction seems to be an overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

In the inductive step, we need to prove,
$$(n-1)^{k+1} \leq n^{k+1}$$
But we earlier we assumed that
$$(n-1)^{k} \leq n^{k}$$
But we can't immediately write $(n-1)^{k+1} \leq n(n-1)$ because we don't know the sign of $(n-1)$

If $n \lt 1$,
$$(n-1) \lt 0 \Rightarrow (n-1)^{k+1} \gt n(n-1)$$ which is not the required answer.

If $n \ge 1$,
$$(n-1) \ge 0 \Rightarrow (n-1)^{k+1} \leq n(n-1)$$ which gives the correct answer after doing what you have done.

Therefore, your original statement is true $iff$ $n \ge 1$, for $\forall k \in \Bbb{N}$